# Plotting CALIPSO data in R

Tags: raster, r, lidar, rgdal, hdf

I am trying to plot one subdataset of CALIPSO which is in hdf format using R. The data is totally new to me as it's LiDAR data. I am not able to understand how to plot a graph between backscatter coefficient (subdataset_42- Total_Backscatter_Coefficient_532) with respect to altitude and latitude (only between 15°-35°) which is also a subdataset. I already asked this question on [@stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187781/plotting-calipso-data-in-r) but, perhaps it fits better here, due to the spatial nature of CALIPSO data and the hdf file format. [The data link is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13g9VBucr1a-X8US5EEG-tnn2FVbnmPpB/view?usp=sharing)

```
library(rgdal)
lbrary(raster)
library(gdalUtils)
gdalinfo("C:/Users/shrav/Downloads/CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58- 
 31ZD_Subset.hdf")
 sds<- get_subdatasets('C:/Users/shrav/Downloads/CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4- 
 20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf')
 r<- raster(sds[42])
  r
```

The example of the plot is [image]

Do you have any suggestion, please? If the data can be conversted to csv then also it'll be helpful as I need to plot it spatially also in ArcGIS .

Comment: Can you point us to the specification for this file? I don't understand it. The latitude is a  641x3 grid, and the longitude is a 641x3 grid, yet the data grids (eg Aerosol Layer Fraction) seem to be 641x399. If you understand the format you can read each into a matrix with `as.matrix(raster(sds[i]))` for `i` in 1 to 53 (the number of sub datasets).

Comment: Am guessing this is the description: https://www-calipso.larc.nasa.gov/resources/calipso_users_guide/data_summaries/profile_data_v420.php but an edit to your Q of which bits you are trying to look at would help.

Comment: I am looking into the sub dataset -Total_Backscattering_coefficient_32-bit floating point and the latitude also 32-bit floating point

Comment: LATitude or ALTitude? The graph above shows ALTitude but you've said LATitude in your last comment. The data has `Surface_Base_Altitude` and `Surface_Top_Altitude`, and there are three latitude and longitude coordinates for each point. We've shown you how to extract the numbers from the data using `terra` and `raster`, if you can go to the data definition and figure out which columns and rows you need then you should be able to work this out. If you can't, then are you going to struggle to understand the meaning of whatever you do with this data?

Comment: Additionally, there's a lot of -9999.0 values in the "Total_Backscatter_Coefficient" data - 97% of it - which seems to indicate missing data. Do you understand the format of this data, and why it is of dimension 641 by 399? I don't see how you can do a simple plot like the one you show (where did that come from?) from a matrix like that.

Comment: I think there's still a lot of processing to do and if you can find a reference to this then that would help. There may even be code already - have you looked? I'm reading stuff like this: https://www.globe.gov/web/s-cool/home/satellite-comparison/how-to-read-a-calipso-satellite-match but I think I've hit my limit since you must be more of an expert in the meaning and understanding of this data than I am...

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/76187781/820534. Please don’t cross-post.

Comment: There is a metadata in the file which contains 399 altitude values. Thus the backscatter coefficient subdataset has 641*399 values. 641 corresponds to the lat/long. And 399 corresponds to the altitude. Also the lat/long dataset is 641*3 size. I only need the first column of the lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can do

```
library(terra)
f <- "CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf"
```

get subdatset level metadata:

```
d <- describe(f, sds=T)
head(d)
#  id                                                                                     name var                                             desc nrow  ncol nlyr
#1  1 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":0   0         [641x3] Latitude (32-bit floating-point)  641     3    1
#2  2 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":1   1        [641x3] Longitude (32-bit floating-point)  641     3    1
#3  3 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":2   2     [641x3] Profile_Time (64-bit floating-point)  641     3    1
#4  4 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":3   3 [641x3] Profile_UTC_Time (64-bit floating-point)  641     3    1
#5  5 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":4   4           [641x1] Day_Night_Flag (8-bit integer)  641     1    1
#6  6 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf":5   5        [641x1] IGBP_Surface_Type (8-bit integer)  641     1    1
```

Read everything as a SpatRasterCollection

```
s <- sprc(f)
s
#class       : SpatRasterCollection 
#length      : 53 
#nrow        : 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, 641, ... 
#ncol        :   3,   3,   3,   3,   1,   1,   1,   2,   4,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, ... 
#nlyr        :   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, ... 
#extent      : 0, 399, 0, 641  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#names       : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
```

The subdatasets have different dimensions. The highest dimensions are:

```
apply(dim(s), 2, max)
#nrow ncol nlyr 
# 641  399    2
```

And the subdatasets with that number of rows and columns are selected when you use `rast`

```
x <- rast(f)

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 641, 399, 17  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 399, 0, 641  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#sources     : CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf:17  
#              CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf:20  
#              CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset.hdf:23  
#              ... and 14 more source(s)
#varnames    : CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset 
#              CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset 
#              CAL_LID_L2_05kmAPro-Standard-V4-20.2015-05-15T07-58-31ZD_Subset 
#              ...
#names       : 17, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, ...
```

To plot subdataset 42 with coordinates you can do the below. As @Spacedman pointed out, the lat and lon rasters have three columns. I am using the middle column and ignoring that I do not know what the number of rows refers to.

```
g <- global(c(s[2][,2,drop=F], s[1][,2,drop=F]), "range")
e <- ext(t(as.matrix(g)))

x <- s[42]
ext(x) <- e
plot(x)
```

Comment: I don't want to plot it as an image as mentioned in my question I only want to plot it as a graph as attached in an example image with my question.

Comment: I think its not a spatial grid, its a linear profile of 641 point samples, each of which has 3 variants on lat-long depending on which bit of the atmosphere its sampling, and then the 399 maps to values at depths in the atmosphere...somehow. The documentation is...fiddly...